# Inheritance clarification (Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function)

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js, contract-invocation, nodejs

I have 3 contracts: User, Patient, and Doctor. Patient and Doctor both inherit from User.

User.sol

```
contract User { 
    // Stuff not relevant for question
    function User() {
        // Constructs 
    }
}
```

Patient.sol

```
contract Patient is User {
    mapping(bytes32 => bytes32[]) category_Records;
    mapping(bytes32 => Record) id_Record;
    // Records
    struct Record {
        bytes32 id;
        bytes32 category;
        address addedBy;
        address addedByContract;
        uint dateAdded;
        bytes32 _hash;
        bool verified;
    }
    // Adding record
    function addRecord(bytes32 _id, bytes32 _category, bytes32 _hash) {
        Record memory newRecord = Record(_id, _category, tx.origin, msg.sender, now, _hash, false);
        id_Record[_id] = newRecord;
        category_Records[_category].push(_id);
    }
}
```

Doctor.sol

```
contract Doctor is User {
    // Adding record
    function addRecord(bytes32 patientID, bytes32 _id, bytes32 _category, bytes32 _hash) {
        // The registry bit is a registry contract which is working
        address _patient = registry.getContractAddress(patientID); 
        // From the registry we get the patient contract address
        Patient patient = Patient(_patient);
        patient.addRecord(_id, _category, _hash);
    }
}
```

I have a button in my front-end which calls

```
contract.user.doctor.addRecord(publicAddress, contractAddress, pID, _id, category, hash);
```

which in turn calls (this function is inside an object contract.user.doctor)

```
function addRecord(publicAddress, contractAddress, pID, _id, category, hash) {
    const input = fs.readFileSync('contracts/All.sol').toString();
    const output = solc.compile(input);
    const bytecode = output.contracts[':Doctor'].bytecode;
    const abi = JSON.parse(output.contracts[':Doctor'].interface);
    const contract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(contractAddress);
    // Insert gas estimation here, default prob insufficient
    contract.addRecord(patientID, _id, _category, _hash, {from: publicAddress}, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('tx: ' + res);
        }
    });
}
```

When I click it, I get back

```
Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function
```

The reason *I think* this is related to inheritance is because I tried, for testing, to make Doctor a standalone (not inherited) contract with only two methods, `getBytes()` and `setBytes()`. When I called from my node app, everything worked fine.

I've checked many times and there is the correct arguments to the Solidity function so I have no idea why it gives me back that error.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're passing `null` for the first argument to the web3 contract object.

This line has `pID`:

```
function addRecord(publicAddress, contractAddress, pID, _id, category, hash) {
```

This one has `patientID`:

```
contract.addRecord(patientID, _id, _category, _hash, {from: publicAddress}, (err, res) => {
```